# You must select a host application to "run" a library

Tags: c, block, codeblocks

I am working with Code::Blocks and trying to program with the C language. I have created a header file, an implementation file and the main. When I compile, I have no errors, but when I run it I get the following error.

You must select a host application to "run" a library...

The libraries are all in the same folder.

I also did include the header files in my main program.

I have tried on 2 different PCs, and it didn't work. i tried with a different piece of code and it worked flawlessly.

What should I do?

Thanks.

EDIT: Solved.

Go to Project -> Properties -> Build Targets

From the 'Type' drop down list select 'Console Application' (in my case).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you have created `dll`. Change to executable.

You may find details how to fix it/

```
Properties -> Build Target -> 'Type' -> Console application
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8506935/2648826

Comment: Or you can create new project as @AShelly suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You have it set up to build a library, not an application.

In File->New Project, you need to choose 'console type'