# Get the running time of a function in c++

Tags: c++, time, performance-testing

I want to calculate the running time of a function for my assignment. I keep getting 0 nut my teacher strictly said that he want some non zero value even for a loop of 10 size. My code so far is this

```
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::nanoseconds;
using std::chrono::steady_clock;

steady_clock::time_point t1 = steady_clock::now();
for(int i=0;i<times;i++){
    bubbleSort(arr,size);
}
steady_clock::time_point t2 = steady_clock::now();
cout<<(float)duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t2-t1).count()/times<<"     ";
```

i have also tried `chrono::high_resolution_clock` , `clock()` and many others.
The main problem is that i have to give some non zero value for `time=1; and size=10`.
Please suggest how could i do this?

Comment: You cannot measure times that are less than a clock resolution.

Comment: What Alex said, also try `high_resolution_clock` in case `steady_clock` is not very high resolution in your OS.

Comment: There is a nested loop in the `bubbleSort` function. Even a simple `cout<<"Hello Worl\n";` gives some non zero value. I don't understand how cout takes more time than nested loop and a check condition

Comment: @vanza I have tried both

Comment: time taken to execute a complete function http://stackoverflow.com/a/40380118/6180077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running your code, commenting the bubbleSort part of course. It is giving some non zero value. Try this :

```
cout<<(float)duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t2-t1).count()/(float)times<<"     ";
```

Comment: @SSMA What compiler are you using? Is it Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes Visual Studio 2012

Comment: @SSMA , try running your code at http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

Comment: @SSMA Visual Studio has problems with the C++11 date and time facilitates. There was a question posted about a year ago from someone with the same problem but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: @Wajahat thanks for your suggestion. It worked on compileonline.com.
But is there a way to make it work on visual studio?

Comment: Why do you really need to run it on visual studio, as @0x499602D2 said there are problems with it.

Comment: @SSMA Repeating what Wajahat asked, why do you need to run it on Visual Studio?

Comment: @Wajahat I have to submit an exe file not the code. I can only create the exe through visual studio.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I have to submit an exe file not the code. I can only create the exe through visual studio.

Comment: I think you can create an exe in other ways also, compilation actually converts it into an executable. Here is a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450121/how-do-i-create-a-exe-from-a-cpp-file-in-code-blocks